# How to mock a global commonjs method with jest?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jasmine, jestjs

I try to test some basic redux reducers with jest and stumbled about a problem I can't solve on my own:

In my reducer I'm referencing a global method "__" (some i18n stuff), which implementation basically looks like the following:

```
window.__ = function(foo) { return window.i18n[foo]; }
```

The mentioned method is referenced in another module I include in my reducer via `import definitions from 'definitions';`

The definitions file looks like the following:

```
/* global __ */
// some basic stuff
export default () {
  return __('foobar');
}
```

How is it possible to mock the `__` method within the test code? Given that `__` is not a module it can't be automocked. :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following syntax to mock the global `__` method:

```
global.__ = function(foo) { return foo; };
```